# No 'MediaTypeFormatter' is available to read an object of type 'String'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, jquery-post

I'm using the ASP.NET Web API. I have an action in my controller which works fine if there's no parameter. If there is a parameter, like:

```
public string UploadFile(string actionType)
```

then my action isn't called and I get the following message,  viewed in Fiddler:

> No 'MediaTypeFormatter' is available to read an object of type 'String' with the media type 'multipart/form-data'

The route in my `global.asx` is as follows:

```
"api/{controller}/{action}/{actionType}"
```

I'm using Jquery Post to call the action:

```
    function upload() {

        var actiontype = $("input:radio[name=actiontype]").val();
        var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]); 

        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/uploads/uploadfile/' + actiontype,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#mydiv").append(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                $("#mydiv").append(data);
            },
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false, 
            processData: false
        });
    };
```

Here's my action method:

```
    public string UploadFile(string actionType)
    {
        if (Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            //Save file
            MultipartFormDataStreamProvider provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files"));
            Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
        }

        return string.Format("Action {0} Complete!", actionType);
    }
```

Is this a known problem, with a workaround? How can I have a simple action with parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the default routes, it looks like you're posting to an incorrect path. This is a common confusion that MVC developers seem to encounter (i know i did).  MVC uses a default path like: `/Controller/Action`.

In web API's default routing setup, however, the action name is skipped (`/api/Controller`) then the method is found through the intersection of the HTTP verb name (post), the method name (Post___) and parameter if necessary.

Assuming you have an API controller named `Uploads`, you should have an action named `PostUploadFile`.

```
   $.ajax({
        url: 'api/uploads/',
        type: 'POST',
```

Some things to notice...

- I started the name of your action with the text "Post..." this matters, the remainder of the name does not
- Your post url was shorted to the name of the controller.
- I went more in depth explaining the [mapping here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10439738/how-does-a-method-in-mvc-webapi-map-to-an-http-verb/10471854#10471854).

---

**EDIT**

Apparently your experiencing an odity of WebAPI.  The way around this is to stuff your "actionType" parameter into a simple object, so model binding can take over.

Rick Strahl explains this and [some other binding oddities here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Mar/21/ASPNET-Web-API-and-Simple-Value-Parameters-from-POSTed-data). There is also [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979123/asp-net-web-api-no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-to-read-an-object-of-type) addressing similar issues.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I'm using Web Forms - I have the Route Template defined as "api/{controller}/{action}/{actionType}"  in the global file - it does expect the action. Remember, it works fine without the parameter there so I suspect it's got s/t to do with that.

Comment: Webforms..huh?  Does your controller inherit from `ApiController` ?  Using firebug/fiddler/whatever ... what is listed in the request header `Accept`? Assuming you're excpecting json back it should be `application/json`.   You may need `dataType: json` as part of your ajax call.

Comment: My controller does inherite from apicontroller. In fiddler, the content-type is 'application/json'. I edited my OP to reflect my current ajax call.

Comment: Thank you! That first link you posted to Rick's blog helped me. I used querystring/ParseQueryString() method (with no action parameter) which seemed to work. Appreciate your help.