# Web API Has Null Parameter For Simple POST

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to call an endpoint using Microsoft's Web API. I'm running into an issue when trying to POST a simple string value. Here is the API controller method.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("search")]
public HttpResponseMessage Search([FromBody] string searchTerm)
{
    // Code ommited for brevity.
}
```

The problem is that the searchTerm variable comes across as null. Here is the raw view of the POST from Fiddler:

```
POST http://localhost:51889/search HTTP/1.1
Host: http://localhost:51889
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
Postman-Token: 4fc51a0c-48ca-a1cd-3df8-70155c3cb5fc
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

searchTerm=dogs
```

I'm sending the request using Postman. [This StackOverflow user had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979123/asp-net-web-api-no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-to-read-an-object-of-type) and one of the answers was to read [Rick Strahl's blog post on the topic](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Mar/21/ASPNET-Web-API-and-Simple-Value-Parameters-from-POSTed-data).
Rick mentions that I need to include the [FromBody] attribute, which I did include. However, this doesn't fix the issue. The only thing I can do to get this to work is to create a new class like so

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("search")]
public HttpResponseMessage Search([FromBody] Search term)
{
    // Code ommited for brevity.
}

public class Search
{
    public string Term { get; set; }
}
```

I would rather not have to create new classes for each POST with simple types like this. Am I missing something? What do I need to change to get simple types to work with my posts without having to create new classes?

Comment: Try removing `[FormBody]` and pass the search term on the url: `search?searchTerm=mySearch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have only one parameter with `[FromBody]` attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("search")]
public HttpResponseMessage Search([FromBody] string term, 
                                 [FromBody] string category // this wouldn't work)
{
    // Code ommited for brevity.
}
```

Therefore WebApi expecting you to have key : `=dogs`.
So if you would've called it with jQuery - you need to use something like this: `$.post('api/test/search', { '': 'dogs' });`

Edit:

Resources:

1. [Practical ASP.NET Web API](http://books.google.com.ua/books?id=rayIAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=web%20api%20media%20formatter%20for%20application/x-www-form-urlencoded&source=bl&ots=ggAxHQOTGS&sig=BOGLRGCW97O5ACBZDm83WlDGYI4&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=E_JtU5a9GKu47QazrIHYDA&ved=0CHIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=web%20api%20media%20formatter%20for%20application/x-www-form-urlencoded&f=false)
2. [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API (MSDN)](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Model binder addresses this issue. From Body is plain wrong

Comment: Why is it plain wrong if it does exactly what it says (binds simple type from http body to CLR type)? In case if I didn't specify [FromBody] - I get 404 because WebAPI by default binds simple types from Uri.

Comment: Because frombody uses a formatter and allows just one parameter

Comment: Could you please provide the code example how ModelBinder attribute fixes the poblem? Because if I just change [FromBody] to [ModelBinder] (from System.Web.Http.ModelBinding) - I get 404.

Comment: Oleksii - You are right. I was thinking about upcoming code we are working on. I'll work on a sample to enable this scenario though, and post here.

Answer (score 0):

try using content tye as application/json instead of application/x-www-form-urlencoded
and also remove formbody from post mehtod parameter

Comment: I changed the content/type to application/json and now I get the 404 error "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI". I also removed the FromBody attribute.

Comment: can i take a look at your post code? are you using form post or jquery post?

Comment: I'm using Postman to make the request. It's a chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the value posted as no key and that it simply begins with =

So, instead of:

```
searchTerm=dogs
```

it should be just

```
=dogs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all parameter value by using model binding like following
create viewmodel class like following :

```
 public class SearchView 
    {
        public string SearchText { get; set; }               
    }
```

add above view model class in your web api like following :

```
[Route("api/Search"), HttpPost]
            public HttpResponseMessage Search(SearchView objSearchView)
            {
```

pass it in your js file like following :

```
var objSearchView = {};
objSearchView.SearchText  = "test";          

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/search',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: data,               
    success: function (response) {
    alert(response);
    },
    error: function (e) {
    alert(e);
    }
});
```